# Trying to print leap years as a vector between user given years

Tags: r, for-loop, leap-year

I am trying to print leap years between user given years as a vector.

```
leap_years<-function(V1,V2){
    for(i in V1:V2){
        if(i%%4==0 && i%%100!=0 ||i%%400==0)
        {print(i)}}}
```

This gives me right years but as a single units. How to get them in single vector?

Comment: Instead of printing append to an accumulative vector. Then print if that is the final goal.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store the results in a vector you will need to store them.
Start by initiating an empty vector, and then instead of printing just append the value to the vector.

I modified your code in that sense:

```r
leap_years<-function(V1,V2){
  leap_vect=NULL
  for(i in V1:V2){
    if(i%%4==0 && i%%100!=0 ||i%%400==0){
      leap_vect = append(leap_vect,i)
      }
    }
return(leap_vect)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can vectorize operations in function `leap_years` like below

```
leap_years <- function(V1,V2) {
  v <- V1:V2
  v[(v%%4==0 & v%%100!=0) | v%%400==0]
}
```

such that

```
> leap_years(1000,2000)
  [1] 1004 1008 1012 1016 1020 1024 1028 1032 1036 1040 1044 1048 1052 1056 1060
 [16] 1064 1068 1072 1076 1080 1084 1088 1092 1096 1104 1108 1112 1116 1120 1124
 [31] 1128 1132 1136 1140 1144 1148 1152 1156 1160 1164 1168 1172 1176 1180 1184
 [46] 1188 1192 1196 1200 1204 1208 1212 1216 1220 1224 1228 1232 1236 1240 1244
 [61] 1248 1252 1256 1260 1264 1268 1272 1276 1280 1284 1288 1292 1296 1304 1308
 [76] 1312 1316 1320 1324 1328 1332 1336 1340 1344 1348 1352 1356 1360 1364 1368
 [91] 1372 1376 1380 1384 1388 1392 1396 1404 1408 1412 1416 1420 1424 1428 1432
[106] 1436 1440 1444 1448 1452 1456 1460 1464 1468 1472 1476 1480 1484 1488 1492
[121] 1496 1504 1508 1512 1516 1520 1524 1528 1532 1536 1540 1544 1548 1552 1556
[136] 1560 1564 1568 1572 1576 1580 1584 1588 1592 1596 1600 1604 1608 1612 1616
[151] 1620 1624 1628 1632 1636 1640 1644 1648 1652 1656 1660 1664 1668 1672 1676
[166] 1680 1684 1688 1692 1696 1704 1708 1712 1716 1720 1724 1728 1732 1736 1740
[181] 1744 1748 1752 1756 1760 1764 1768 1772 1776 1780 1784 1788 1792 1796 1804
[196] 1808 1812 1816 1820 1824 1828 1832 1836 1840 1844 1848 1852 1856 1860 1864
[211] 1868 1872 1876 1880 1884 1888 1892 1896 1904 1908 1912 1916 1920 1924 1928
[226] 1932 1936 1940 1944 1948 1952 1956 1960 1964 1968 1972 1976 1980 1984 1988
[241] 1992 1996 2000
```